# Add the same armature to the parent and his child

Tags: animation, armature, blender-internal-render-engine, unity, .fbx

I have a problem with exporting .fbx file with animation. I have one animation (for now), "Open the first drawer" (look at the model picture).

[image]

Currently, the Armature object is a parent to the drawer and handle (Drawer and handler are not in Parent-Child connection). If I export the model like this, its animation works fine! But if I connect the Handler object to the Drawer object (Parent-child connection) and export that, the animation will go crazy.

**Good animation**

[image]

[image]

**Bad animation**

[image]

[image]

I'm a beginner at using animation in the blender and I don't know the right way for solving this issue. What I wanna do? I wanna connect the handle to its drawer (Parent-Child) and connect Drawer/Handle to the Armature which is used for opening actions.

Comment: you can create an armature with 2 bones, and create one object with 3 meshes: the drawers and one drawer with its handle. Make one bone the root bone, parent a second bone to this root bone, and parent the drawer + handle to this second bone, and it should work

Comment: @moonboots I created one armature and then subdivided the bone into 2 pieces. Is that the correct way to create an armature with 2 bones?

Comment: you need now to select the second bone and Alt P (Clear Parent) > Disconnect Bone. The bone is still child but it is not sticked to its parent any more.